# Why is a loop not working inside a passive informatica java transform?

Tags: java, loops, informatica

I am looping through an array in a `java` transform, writing some of the elements to outputs in the same row (passive).
The loop stops at the 1st iteration

```
        for (int c = 1 ; c < arr.length; c++){

                String fldname = String.valueOf(c);
                int fldIdx  = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty(fldname));

                if( isOutFldProjected( fldname) && 
                        (!isSetNullCalled( fldname))){

                    outputBuf.setString(outRowNum, fldIdx, arr[c]);
                }
```

Comment: Is there any error occurred? Or the just only stopped after the first iteration.

Comment: No errors - when I write the iterator value c to an output, it is always 1; the code works in eclipse; arr.length is 16

Comment: What is the value of  `arr.length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your arr contains 16 elements and it exiting in first iteration, it must throw some kind of Error or Exception. Which you should be getting at output console.

Or Loop may be iterating 16 times but without meeting your if condition :

```
if( isOutFldProjected( fldname) && (!isSetNullCalled( fldname)))
```

Try debugging.

If I missed any info please provide.

Answer (score 1):

Post the detailed information. Unable to understand the whole problem.
But I think your arr[] has only one element in it.

Comment: No when I write the length to output, it was = 16